# Python: Regular expression use re.search

Tags: python, regex, csv, file-io

I am iterating over directory structure that has many csv files, I am only interest some of the the csv files that are in that directory:

```
    if os.path.exists(lang_dir):
        dirs = os.listdir(lang_dir)
        for filename in dirs:
            if re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$',filename):
```

but for some reason file name with `zu-en-template-users-data.csv` doesn't get recognize, I have a feeling that the letter `u` in the filename has something to do with. Just to double check above segment of code, I directly went to folder and tried it with python interpreter, and with python interpreter files did get recognized correctly.

```
>>> import re
>>> import os
>>> dirs = os.listdir("PATH_FOR_THE_DIR/Data/2013_03_06_20_34/zu")
>>> for item in dirs:
...     if re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$',item):
...             print item
... 
zu-ab-template-users-data.csv
zu-ace-template-users-data.csv
zu-af-template-users-data.csv
zu-ak-template-users-data.csv
zu-als-template-users-data.csv
...
```

As you can see all the files that starts with `zu` showed up.. This means that my regular expression code segment is correct? (to my understanding)

And here is my code:

```
def templateUserCountStats(root_dir_path, lang_code_file_path):
    #dictionary to hold the template count data structure
    template_count_dict = dict()
    # getting lang codes from csv file
    for lang in getLanguageCodes(lang_code_file_path):
        # root level key of the dictionary
        template_count_dict[lang] = dict()
        lang_dir = os.path.join(root_dir_path, lang)
        # get all the files as s list in lang dir
        if os.path.exists(lang_dir):
            dirs = os.listdir(lang_dir)
            for filename in dirs:
                if re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$',filename):
                    lang2 = filename.split("-")[1]
                    #path = os.path.join(lang_dir, filename)
                    path = os.path.expanduser(lang_dir + '/' + filename)
                    #with open(path, 'rb') as template_user_data_file:
                    try:
                        template_user_data_file = open(path, 'r')
                        try:
                            csv_file_reader = csv.reader(template_user_data_file)
                            csv_file_reader.next()
                            # initializing user count for each language
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2] = dict()
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] = 0
                            #print filename
                            for row in csv_file_reader:
                                if row[0] == '1':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] + 1
                                if row[0] == '2':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] + 1
                                if row[0] == '3':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] + 1
                                if row[0] == '4':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] + 1
                                if row[0] == '5':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] + 1
                                if row[0] == 'N':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] + 1
                        except csv.Error, e:
                            print e
                    except Exception, e:
                        print e
                        logging.error(e)
            else:
                print "path doesn't exist"
    return template_count_dict
```

Comment: First you say that `zu-en-template-users-data.csv` isn't matched, then you say that all the files that start with `zu` are matched.  What actually happens, and what do you want to happen?  Are you sure the file `zu-en-template-users-data.csv` even exists in the first place?  (Also, I assure you that a bare `u` is not treated specially by a regular expression.)

Comment: Why aren't you using Python's `glob` module?

Comment: I just edited the question. I thought my regula expression is incorrect so I tried it with python interpreter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this because regular expression some how interpret u as a pattern...?

No this can't be the reason.

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$', 'zu-en-template-users-data.csv'))
True
```

Your re pattern should work, the problem is somewhere else.